# Constant term of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $D_e$ be the exterior of a simply connected contour *C* on z-plane, it may be conformally mapped onto the exterior of the unit disk $|\zeta|>1$ by $z=m(\zeta)$ where from Laurent's theorem

$\qquad z=m(\zeta) = a_1\zeta + a_0 + b_1\zeta^{-1} + b_2\zeta^{-2} + \cdots + b_n\zeta^{-n} + \cdots.$

In *Complex Variable Methods in Elasticity, Ch.5*, it is stated that we can arrange that

$\qquad a_0=0 \quad and \quad a_1 \in \mathbb{R},$

by choice of $\zeta$-axes, such that

$\qquad z=m(\zeta) = R\zeta + b_1\zeta^{-1} + b_2\zeta^{-2} + \cdots. + b_n\zeta^{-n} + \cdots, \quad R \in \mathbb{R}.$

How do I find the proper $\zeta$-axes?

Writing $a_1$ in polar coordinate, $a_1=Re^{i\theta}$, and let $\hat{\zeta} = e^{i\theta}\zeta$, then

$$
\begin{align}
z = m(\zeta) &= Re^{i\theta}\zeta + a_0 + b_1\zeta^{-1} + b_2\zeta^{-2} + \cdots. + b_n\zeta^{-n} + \cdots \\
&=R\hat\zeta + a_0 + b_1e^{i\theta}\hat\zeta^{-1} + b_2e^{2i\theta}\hat\zeta^{-2} + \cdots. + b_ne^{ni\theta}\hat\zeta^{-n} + \cdots.
\end{align}
$$

This way the first order term coefficient becomes real, but how to eliminate the constant term $a_0$?